# How to save old position of an element in sharedpreferences after Search filtering the listview

Tags: android, search, android-listview, sharedpreferences

I implemented the code for filtering and also saving the position of the selected element in the listview. After the user makes search in the listview via editText a new list is created. When the user clicks on the element the position of it is being saved in **sharedpreferences**. By reopening the app, this position is needed but not the position from the filtered listview. It should be the right position of the original one. I didnt find any way to do this in my code. 
I would really appreciate any help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saving position is not a convenient way to achieve the solution. Rather you need to store any unique value of the list.

Suppose, you are showing a list of `Person` and filtering the list based on user search. So, every Person will have one id say, `p_id`which is unique. Try to save `p_id` in your `SharedPreference`.

Then after reopening the app check the `p_id` of original list and mark then check or uncheck.

Comment: Thank you very much i understand what you mean but i have a picture "checked" "unchecked" boxes which change with "onitemclick" how do i solve this ?

Comment: Can you add some code snippets as well. It's difficult to understand your problem.

Comment: Ok im implementing my code with your advice i ll post it in a while thank you

Comment: just added an id field to my class and that solved it thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your element should have its position as a field. Initialize the position during initialization or addition to the list.

Comment: I had to choose one answer if i could be able to choose two yours would be there too thank you very much